# Алгоритм удаления дублей в большом файле

Tags: c, алгоритм, файлы

Дан файл с десятичными цифрами, записанными построчно. Минимальное кол-во разрядов в числе 9, максимальное — 15. Всего в файле может быть от 3 до 10 млн. таких строк.

Нужно удалить дубли. Я пытался использовать такой алгоритм на Си:

```
FILE *fin, *fout;
unsigned long long int n, N=1000000000000000;//10^15
unsigned *arr=0;
arr = (unsigned*)calloc(N,sizeof(unsigned));
while (!feof(fin)){
    fscanf(fin,"%lli",&n);
    if (arr[n]==0){
         arr[n]=1;
         fprintf(fout,"%lli",n)
    }
}
```

Алгоритм работает до *N = 10<sup>8</sup>*. Ошибка возникает уже при *N = 10<sup>9</sup>*.

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы работало? Или надо менять полностью алгоритм? Тогда как по другому решить эту задачу?

Comment: ну то что 10^9 интов просто нельзя выделить для 32-битных систем. Посмотрите сколкьо вы памяти просите и подумайте сколько у вас есть.

Comment: Ну алгоритм полюбому менять в корне, потому как я не знаю где вы найдете компьютер с 4 петабайтами оперативной памяти

Comment: Думаю подошла бы какая нибудь хеш-таблица, с цепочками элементов при коллизии

Comment: @Mike на 32 бита ничего не поможет...

Comment: @pavel В условиях задачи всего 10 млн чисел на входе. 24 битный хеш может пройти с минимумом коллизий. памяти хватит

Comment: язык любой? или именно C?

Comment: желательно С, но если есть идеи на другом - не откажусь

Answer (score 2):

Если язык не принципиален - то вот решение на C# через стандартный `Distinct`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\out.txt",
    File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\in.txt")
        .Select(long.Parse)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(n => n.ToString())
    );
```

На C - тот же подход. Взять любую реализацию хэш-таблицы для проверки уникальности и прогнать через нее содержимое файла, добавляя в нее + записывая в выходной поток те значения, которых в таблице нет.

Comment: Вроде 15 цифр влезет и в `long`.

Comment: @VladD хм, да, с запасом :)

Comment: @VladD Так ведь смотря какой `long` - если обычный 32-битный, то никак, только в `long long` - если таковой 64 бита, конечно...

Comment: @Harry ответ дан на C#. В C# long является синонимом для System.Int64

Comment: @PavelMayorov А, все, тогда умолкаю. С С с четырьмя крестами :) не знаком.

Comment: @Harry: Вроде ж всего два креста, только поближе :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/4znEx.png

Comment: @VladD Да, так я это не рассматривал... Нет уж, пусть лучше четыре - чем дальше от ++, тем лучше :) Кстати, это отдельный философский разговор, но как по мне - чем ближе языки друг к другу, тем сложнее работать на обоих...

Answer (score 1):

Да в чем проблема? 15 байт, 10 миллионов - итого 150 мегабайт... Если разово посчитать - можно даже вектором строк (!). Считываем в память, сортируем, убираем за один проход все смежные одинаковые...

Вот такая простая и тупая программка у меня отработала (часть чтения, сортировки и удаления дублей) за 7.5 секунд.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int N = 10000000;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<long long> v;
    vector<long long>::iterator last;
    v.reserve(N);
    {
        ofstream out("out");
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            out << rand() << "00000000\n";
        }
    }
    {
        long long s;
        {
            ifstream in("out");
            while(in >> s) v.push_back(s);
        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());
        last = unique(v.begin(),v.end());
    }
    {
        ofstream out("out2");
        for(auto it = v.begin(); it != last; ++it)
        {
            out << *it << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, вариант с хешированием отработал часть чтения и хеширования за те же 7 секунд.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int N = 10000000;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        ofstream out("out");
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            out << rand() << "00000000\n";
        }
    }
    unordered_set<long long> v;
    v.reserve(N);
    {
        ifstream in("out");
        long long s;
        while(in >> s) v.insert(s);
    }
    {
        ofstream out("out2");
        for(auto s: v)
        {
            out << s << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и на C вся программа отработала за 10 секунд (тут у меня удаление одинаковых сшито с записью, время не разделишь...):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int N = 10000000;

int comp(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    long long l1 = *(long long*)p1;
    long long l2 = *(long long*)p2;
    return
        (l1 > l2) ? 1 :
        (l1 < l2) ? -1 : 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE * out = fopen("out","wt");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(out,"%d00000000\n",rand());
    }
    fclose(out);

    long long * s = malloc(N*sizeof(long long));

    FILE * in = fopen("out","rt");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(in,"%lld",&s[i]);
    }
    fclose(in);

    qsort(s,N,sizeof(long long),comp);

    out = fopen("out2","wt");
    long long last = s[0];
    fprintf(out,"%lld\n",last);
    for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == last) continue;
        fprintf(out,"%lld\n",last=s[i]);
    }
    fclose(out);

}
```

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим.
Harry, удивительно быстро работает  qsort. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устроил, помечайте как принятый :)